# How to disable compatibility header in Elasticsearch Java API Client?

Tags: java, kotlin, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm trying to config my application to interaction with Elastcisearch server v7.7 using [Java API Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html) v7.16.3. But when I try to index new document, I get the following error:

```
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=7] is not supported","status":406}
```

As far as I understand, the reason is the [compatibility `Content-type` header](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/api-conventions.html) which value contains `compatible-with=7`. Elasticsearch v7.7 doesn't support this content-type (while Elasticsearch v7.15 works fine with it). Here is my configuration:

```
    fun configElasticsearchRestClient(
        host: String,
        username: String,
        password: String
    ): ElasticsearchClient {
        val elasticsearchRestClient =  RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(host))
            .build()
        val transport: ElasticsearchTransport = RestClientTransport(
            elasticsearchRestClient,
            JacksonJsonpMapper()
        )
        return ElasticsearchClient(transport)
    }
```

And here is indexing method:

```
    fun index(document: SomeDocument) {
        val indexRequest = IndexRequest.Builder<ObjectNode>()
            .index("some-index")
            .document(document)
            .id(document.getId())
            .version(document.getVersion())
            .versionType(External)
            .build()

        elasticsearchClient.index(indexRequest)
    }
```

Is it possible do disable compatibility headers for Java API Client?
Or is there any another way to use Java API Client for Elasticsearch server v7.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use a client library version that is compatible with the server version. In this case you're using a recent version of the client library (i.e. 7.16.3) with an older version of the server (i.e. 7.7), you're not supposed to do that, or you should [expect some backward incompatibility issues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html):

> The client must have the same major version (e.g. 2.x, or 5.x) as the nodes in the cluster. Clients may connect to clusters which have a different minor version (e.g. 2.3.x) but **it is possible that new functionality may not be supported.** Ideally, the client should have the same version as the cluster.

If you use the [Java client 7.7](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.7/index.html) instead, you won't have any problems.

Also, as you can see from the latest [Java Client source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/35a79bc7d404bd8181a97b32a86db8962c953933/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java#L2490-L2566), the `compatible-with` value is hardcoded into the HTTP header value. If a header is found to not have that compatibility check, it is [modified automatically](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/35a79bc7d404bd8181a97b32a86db8962c953933/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java#L2623-L2660) to include it, so there's no way to turn it off.

Comment: Thank you for explaination!
I understand that I'm not able to use all the features of the client when I use the client v7.16 and server v7.7.
But I expected to be able to use all the features of version 7.7, because the major versions of server and client are the same.

Comment: Yes, except for that compatibility check getting in the way

Comment: @Val my elastic search version is 7.5.1 . Does this means i can't use java elastic search client https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html as its minimum version is 7.15.0